# Excel Function running with Blank cells

Tags: excel

I have this Function in excel

```
=(IF(AND(E6>=8.91,E6<=9.09),"Pass","Fail"))
```

This code works perfectly. However, I do not wish for "Fail" to show up when no data is entered in my E6 column.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: wrap it in another if statement to check for blank cells

Comment: What do you want it to show?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way :

```
=IF(E6="","",IF(AND(E6>=8.91,E6<=9.09),"Pass","Fail"))
```